# SQL: cube function incorrectly terminated

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sum, cube

Simple syntax error using Oracle 11g. With the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT employee, CUST_NBR,
SUM (SALE_PRICE)
FROM CUST_ORDER
GROUP BY employee, CUST_NBR WITH CUBE
```

For the table CUST_ORDER (*ORDER_ID, employee, SALE_PRICE, CUST_NBR)

Oracle complains that

> ERROR at line 4:  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I am probably being blind, but I can't see the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
GROUP BY CUBE(employee, CUST_NBR)
```

More on `CUBE` [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets.php).